# DataBase return works on start, but not on update

Tags: c#, mysql, database

So I have an interesting problem... I have an app that runs, but needs a value in the "OrderID.text". The value is then searched in the MySQL database, and returns the information I need. In this case, the telephone number.

When I include the value in the code. (for example, newCurrentID = 8), it returns the telephone number. However, I want the user to have the ability to enter his own value, and the telephone number changes to the user's preferences.

When I input a value, the MessageBox works after I press enter, but the Telephone's textbox remains blank. Any Ideas????

Im only including the code thats relevant to this.

```
public partial class Form1:
{
    //the rest is just design code for the app.
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.orderID.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.EnterKey);
        this.orderID.Text = "";
        this.phoneNumber.Text = DB_App.phone_number;
        this.phoneNumber.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.phoneNumber_TextChanged);
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private DBApplication DB_App;

    public Form1()
    {
        DB_App = new DBApplication(this);
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // I assigned a value to this to make sure the MySQL connection worked.
    public int newCurrentID;

    private void EnterKey(object o, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
        {
            if (!int.TryParse(orderID.Text, out newCurrentID))
                MessageBox.Show("not a number");
            else
            {
                int.TryParse(orderID.Text, out newCurrentID);
                //I used this to make sure the "newCurrentID" was being read.
                //MessageBox.Show(newCurrentID.ToString()); 
            }
            DB_App.OrderID();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    private void phoneNumber_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}

public class DBApplication : DBInfo
{
    public DBApplication(Form1 form)
    {
        this.Form = form;
        OrderID();
        CloseConnection();
    }

    //my guess is that the problem is somewhere in here, but im not certain.
    public void OrderID()
    {
        customer_id = this.Form.newCurrentID;
        //add the DataBase query to the string.

        query = "SELECT * FROM wdb_customer WHERE customer_id= @customer_id";

        if (OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            //MySqlCommand myComm = connection.CreateCommand();
            MySqlCommand myComm = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            MySqlDataReader Reader;
            //myComm.CommandText = query;
            //myComm.Connection = connection;
            myComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customer_id", customer_id);
            Reader = myComm.ExecuteReader();

            while (Reader.Read())
            {
                lastname = Reader["customer_name"].ToString();
                phone_number = Reader["customer_telephone"].ToString();
            }
            Reader.Close();
        }

        CloseConnection();
        //return lastname;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please include the `this.phoneNumber_TextChanged` method?

Comment: yeah sorry.

its blank at the moment though. a blank method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no indication that your Form would know about the fact that the phonenumber inside your database class has changed. Consider a design, where your DBApplication *does not know* the Form. You can pass in parameters to the function (newCurrentID) and you can return values to the Form (phonenumber), which the Form then needs to put into it's text fields.

**Edit:**

You need to think of your functions in more professional terms. Currently you have two parties and a transaction. For example a merchant and a customer and the customer wants to buy a candy bar.

**Your current behaviour is:**

```
void Purchase();
```

Behind the scenes, the merchant stuffs the candy bar up the customers throat, while with the other hand trying to finger the money from the customers purse. Both know each other and both took notes who the other guy was.  *If a merchant were like that, I would take notes, too!*

**What you need to implement is a professional deal:**

```
CandyBar Purchase(money);
```

The customer hands over the money, the merchant gives the candy bar. After the transaction, both do with their respective goods what ever they want. Both forget each other right after the transaction.

Your deal is, your database hands over the data when it gets a customer number:

```
public class CustomerData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}


public class DataStore
{
    // this is a clean description of your "deal", there's nothing behind the scenes.
    public CustomerData GetCustomerByID(int orderID)
    {
       CustomerData customer = null;

       // somehow get data from database as before using customerID
       customer = new CustomerData { Name = "John Smith", PhoneNumber = "555-123456789" };

       return customer; 
    }
}
```

And your form is responsible for actually getting that number from your user and putting the results back in the UI:

```
public class Form1
{
private DataStore data;

// call this any time the user changes something
    private void UpdateData()
    {
        int orderID;
        if (int.TryParse(orderID.Text, out orderID))
        {
            var customer = data.GetCustomerByID(orderID);
            this.phoneNumber.Text = customer.PhoneNumber;
            // this.name.Text = customer.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that suddenly, the amount of stuff that need to be public was reduced to only the one clean GetCustomerByID interface.

Comment: omg... i think your right. just tried something.

What would you recommend I do? Im trying a few things, to see if any of them work.

Comment: Added some recommendations.

Comment: WOOT FINALLY THANK YOU!
you know that moment in time when you been working on the same exact thing for 5 hours and you get this feeling after it starts working?? yeah I feel like that right now :)